# how do i deal with this dependency injection error?

Tags: c#

i am creating a website using full stack and one of my controllers is failing to inject an interface and am getting the following error from the browser:

InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'SolarCoffee.Services.Product.IProductService' while attempting to activate 'SolarCoffee.Web.Controllers.ProductController'.

my code is as follows
//startup

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using SolarCoffee.Data;
using Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Stripe;
using SolarCoffee.Services.Product;
namespace SolarCoffee.Web
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get;  }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddControllers();
        services.AddDbContext<SolarDbContext>(opts =>
        
            //opts.UseNpgsql("solar.dev=ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection")
        //);
        {
            opts.EnableDetailedErrors();
            opts.UseNpgsql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Data Source = solar.dev"));
        });
        services.AddScoped<IProductService, Services.Product.ProductService>();
        
    }

    //this method gets called by the runtime. use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseAuthorization(); 

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }

}
```

}

//controller

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using SolarCoffee.Data.Models;
using SolarCoffee.Services.Product;

namespace SolarCoffee.Web.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    public class ProductController : ControllerBase
    {
    private readonly ILogger<ProductController> _logger;
    private readonly IProductService _productService;

    [ActivatorUtilitiesConstructor]
    public ProductController(ILogger<ProductController> logger, IProductService productService)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _productService = productService;
    }

    [HttpGet("api/product")]
    public ActionResult GetProduct()
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Getting all products");
        var products = _productService.GetAllProducts();
        return Ok(products);
    }
}
```

}

//service interface

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace SolarCoffee.Services.Product
{
    public interface IProductService
    {
        List<Data.Models.Product> GetAllProducts();
        Data.Models.Product GetProductById(int id);
        ServiceResponce<Data.Models.Product> CreateProduct(Data.Models.Product product);
        ServiceResponce<Data.Models.Product> ArchiveProduct(int id);
    }
}
```

//interface implementation

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using SolarCoffee.Data;
using SolarCoffee.Data.Models;
using SolarCoffee.Services.Product;

namespace SolarCoffee.Services.Product
{
public class ProductService : IProductService
{
    private readonly SolarDbContext _db;

    public ProductService(SolarDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _db = dbContext;
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Archives a product by setting setting boolean IsArchived to true
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="id"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public ServiceResponce<Data.Models.Product> ArchiveProduct(int id)
    {
        try
        {
            var product = _db.Products.Find(id);
            product.IsArchived = true;
            _db.SaveChanges();

            return new ServiceResponce<Data.Models.Product>
            {
                Data = product,
                Time = DateTime.UtcNow,
                Message = "Archived product",
                IsSuccess = true
            };
        }
         catch (Exception e)
        {
            return new ServiceResponce<Data.Models.Product>
            {
                Data = null,
                Time = DateTime.UtcNow,
                Message = e.StackTrace,
                IsSuccess = false
            };
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds a new product by primary key
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="product"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public ServiceResponce<Data.Models.Product> CreateProduct(Data.Models.Product product)
    {
        try
        {
            _db.Products.Add(product);

            var newInventory = new ProductInventory
            {
                Product = product,
                QuantityOnHand = 0,
                IdealQuantity = 10,
            };

            _db.ProductInventries.Add(newInventory);

            _db.SaveChanges();

            return new ServiceResponce<Data.Models.Product>
            {
                Data = product,
                Time = DateTime.UtcNow,
                Message = "Saved new product",
                IsSuccess = true
            };
        }
   
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return new ServiceResponce<Data.Models.Product>
            {
                Data = product,
                Time = DateTime.UtcNow,
                Message = "Error saving new product",
                IsSuccess = true
            };
        }
      
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Retrives all products from the database
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public List<Data.Models.Product> GetAllProducts()
    {
        return _db.Products.ToList();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Retrieves a Product from the database by primary key
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="id"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public Data.Models.Product GetProductById(int id)
    {
        return _db.Products.Find(id);
    }
}
```

}

i am failing to see where am getting it wrong

Comment: Your code looks fine for the first glance. Is this the full error what you get? Have you checked the inner exceptions for additional information?

Comment: What happens if you remove the `ActivatorUtilitiesConstructor` attribute from the ProductController's constructor?

Comment: Most likely, SolarDBContext creation threw exception. 
Try to remark the Context object for now and retry.

Comment: @nemesv if i remove the ActivatorUtilitiesConstructor attribute it still behaves the same

Comment: but one of my nuget packages is giving me this warning i dont know if it has an effect: 
Warning NU1701 Package 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices 2.2.0' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework 'net6.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project. SolarCoffee.Services C:\Users\stycs\solarCoffee\SolarCoffee.Services\SolarCoffee.Services.csproj 1

Comment: Any inner exceptions?

Comment: there are no inner exceptions

Comment: i believe there is some compatibility issues with the sdk version that am using so have downgraded and started the project. i will notify if there is a change

Comment: so the problem was with my sdk. some of the nu-get packages were not compatible for the .net6.0 i was using so i downgraded to 3.1 and the error disappeared

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so the problem was with my sdk. some of the nu-get packages were not compatible for the .net6.0 i was using so i downgraded to 3.1 and the error disappeared

Comment: Please mark your answer as approved one if that resolved your issue.